# How to add both value and id to html drop down option tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add options in to the select box dynamically. This is my HTML

```
<select id="RightPriceMulRetail" class="form-control"></select>
```

And this is my JavaScript code

```
$("#RightPriceMulRetail").get(0).options.length = 0;
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
 $("#RightPriceMulRetail").get(0).options[$("#RightPriceMulRetail").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.sellPrice, item.qty);
});
```

This is working fine and result like this

```
<option value="qty">sell Price</option>
```

Now my question is i need to add **ID attribute to option** like bellow using my JavaScript

```
<option value="qty" id="someValue">sell Price</option>
```

Can any one help me with this.

Comment: Just set the new option you're creating to a variable, and then call `$(var).attr("id",my-id-value);` before you add it to the options array.

Comment: you can't add the id-value that way, but you can put the id-value *into* the value-attribute eg  `<option value="qty-someValue">sell Price</option>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an element using jQuery syntax easily, then use .appendTo() to add that to the select

```
var $select = $("#RightPriceMulRetail").empty();
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    $('<option />', {
        value: item.qty,
        text: item.sellPrice,
        id: 'someid'
    }).appendTo($select)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/byyen3mv/)

Comment: can u say how to select option by that id

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana `$('#myid').prop('selected', true)`

Comment: how can select id another select box using id. i mean i have 2 drop downs. how can i specifically say select id from which drop down

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana ID of an element must be unique... is there a way to know which select you want to target

Comment: i have same ids on my both drop downs

Comment: there i found solution

Comment: $("#RightPriceMulRetail option[id='4']").prop('selected', true)

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana yes it is